# Angular: Porque no sirve mi scroll dentro de un div?

Tags: css, angular

Estoy imprimiendo un arreglo de 100 números dentro de una llamada a un componente, es decir, en mi componente padre llamo al hijo, el cual imprime los 100

padre.component.html

```
<div class="izq">
<div class="message-box">
  <app-text-box  [chat]="newChat" ></app-text-box>
</div>
```

App text box es donde se imprimen 100 veces los datos

text-box.component.ts

```
<div *ngFor="let num of numbers" >
    {{num}}
</div>
```

Estos son los datos pero en el app-text-box quiero que se agrege un scroll en ese div, pero no funciona, intente hacerlo desde el componente hijo que es el de text-box agregando la propiedad overflow, pero no funciona, tambien lo intente en el padre, en la clase `message-box` pero tampoco funciona, ya le defini la altura y el ancho, no entiendo porque no funciona, no se si es correcto ponerlo en el div de `message-box` o en el `app-text-box`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para agregar un scroll a un div en Angular, puedes utilizar la propiedad CSS overflow junto con una altura fija para el contenedor.

Podrías pobar así :

```
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div *ngFor="let num of numbers">
    {{num}}
  </div>
</div>

.scroll-container {
  height: 200px; /* Ajusta la altura según tus necesidades */
  overflow: auto;
}
```